# Подключения Webmoney merchant api на своём сайте

Tags: php, laravel, webmoney

Я работаю с фреймворком Laravel. Пытаюсь подключить web-money merchant api на своём сайте. Посмотрел готовый api на гитхабе https://github.com/baibaratsky/php-webmoney/wiki/X2, но мне этот код вообще не знаком. Нужен ли xml интерфейс, как конвертируется руб на usd, как я узнаю что транзакция прошла успешно чтобы обновить баланс на сайте. Если у кого нибудь есть простой пример с русскими комментариями кода, пожалуйста помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда-то делал что-то подобное когда учил php
Для приема оплаты вам нужен X20 интерфейс список всех [Интерфейсов](http://wiki.webmoney.ru/projects/webmoney/wiki/XML-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8B)

Еще есть готовый sdk от webmoney для php на [github](https://github.com/baibaratsky/php-webmoney)
Если вкратце без использования сторонних библиотек вам нужно построить пост запрос из параметров которые описаны в интерфейсе, а в ответ вам придет ответ из котором и будет ясно, прошел платеж или нет, все это описано в офф. доке.

P.S. Выставляете в настройках для кошелька тестовые платежи и пробуете все это делать. Так-же если я не ошибаюсь для этого нужен персональный аттестат.
Удачи!